# How can I use bmesh vert index as vertex color index?

Tags: vertices, color, bmesh

I want to modify the vertex color by index, the bmesh vertex index value seems unequal to the colorlayer.data index, so it's difficult to draw a vert with several mesh cross.
Is there any to fix this problem? Thank you!

````
import bpy
import bmesh

# Set in objecte mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

# get current mesh
#current_mesh = bpy.data.object.data
#current_mesh = bpy.object.data


# bmesh seems imposible to set vertex color, use a substitution to work like this
current_mesh = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data
current_mesh_color = bpy.data.objects['Cube.002'].data

# vert color check
if not current_mesh_color.vertex_colors:
    current_mesh_color.vertex_colors.new()
    
# get vertex color layer this seas to be unuseful when use bmesh and try to set color data by bmesh data
# current_coler_layer = current_mesh.vertex_colors["Col"]
# use a substitution object to cacute the color 
current_coler_layer = current_mesh_color.vertex_colors["Col"]


#--------------------------------------------Bmesh data Get
# create empty bmesh, add current mesh into empty bmesh
current_bm = bmesh.new()
current_bm.from_mesh(current_mesh)
current_bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

# TODO: get absolute position
# get location of face (atm it relative to object origin)
# bpy.context.object.matrix_world for world position left muli

i = 0
for face in current_bm.faces:
    
#    #current face center coord
    face_center_coord = face.calc_center_median()
    
    for vert in face.verts:
        # this will loop some repetitive vertex severals times
        
        # get vert index
        current_vert_index = vert.index
        # get vert coord
        current_vert_coord = vert.co
        
        x = face_center_coord.x*0.5+0.5
        y = face_center_coord.y*0.5+0.5
        z = current_vert_coord.z
        
        # Seemingly look like that the vert index is not equale to the color layer index, just use a selfradd varible can work well
        # Unity use y for up direction, left hand axis
        current_coler_layer.data[i].color = (x, z, y, 1.0)
        
        print(current_vert_index)  # DEBUG
        i+=1

# current_bmesh back to mesh
current_bm.to_mesh(current_mesh)
current_bm.free()
#--------------------------------------------
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Vertex colors are not stored on a vertex, they are stored on a loop (loop = corner of a poly). This means one vertex can have different vertex colors for each poly it is part of. So you would need to index into `mesh.vertex_colors["Col"].data` using the loop index.

However, if you're using a bmesh, you can set the vertex color for a loop with `loop[layer] = (r, g, b, a)` where layer is `your_bmesh.loops.layers.color[your_layer_name]`.

Try this:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

current_mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data

current_bm = bmesh.new()
current_bm.from_mesh(current_mesh)
current_bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

# TODO: get absolute position
# get location of face (atm it relative to object origin)
# bpy.context.object.matrix_world for world position left muli

# Get first color layer (create if needed)
if not current_bm.loops.layers.color:
    current_bm.loops.layers.color.new('Col')
layer = current_bm.loops.layers.color[0]

for face in current_bm.faces:
    # Current face center coord
    face_center_coord = face.calc_center_median()

    for loop in face.loops:
        # get vert coord
        current_vert_coord = loop.vert.co

        x = face_center_coord.x*0.5+0.5
        y = face_center_coord.y*0.5+0.5
        z = current_vert_coord.z

        # Unity use y for up direction, left hand axis
        loop[layer] = (x, z, y, 1.0)

# current_bmesh back to mesh
current_bm.to_mesh(current_mesh)
current_bm.free()
```

Tested with Blender 2.90.